# Ajax CrossDomain Error :" Unexpected token :"

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, webservice, jsonp

Al  traer datos desde un servicio de la AFIP  me tira el  error 
 "Unexpected token :".

Al parecer el tipo de dato que devuelve es incorrecto,alguna solución? gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código Js es el siguiente:

```
 var WSAFIP="https://soa.afip.gob.ar/sr-padron/v2/persona/";
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                     jsonp: 'jsonp',
                      jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                    contentType: 'text/json',
                   //contentType: 'text',
                    callback: function (result) {
                        if (result != null && result != undefined) {
                            for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++)
                                data.push(result[i].word);
                        }
                    },

                     //  crossDomain: true,
                   // data: { index: at.toString(), entities: en.toString(), word: wo.toString() },
                    url:  WSAFIP + $cuit.val()+ '?format=json&callback=w',//'?jsonp=callme',
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result != null && result != undefined) {
                            for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++)
                                data.push(result[i].word);
                        }
                    },

                error: function(data) {
                var s=data;
                },
                });
```

Json devuelto :

```
{"success":true,"data":{"idPersona":33709585229,"tipoPersona":"JURIDICA","tipoClave":"CUIT","estadoClave":"ACTIVO","nombre":"GOOGLE ARGENTINA S.R.L.","domicilioFiscal":{"direccion":"MOREAU DE JUSTO A.AV 350 Piso:2","codPostal":"1107","idProvincia":0},"idDependencia":10,"mesCierre":12,"fechaInscripcion":"2006-04-07","fechaContratoSocial":"2006-03-29","impuestos":[353,218,10,30,25,211,103,217,301],"actividades":[731009,620900,711003],"caracterizaciones":[68,72,255]}}
```

Comment: puedes dejar en tu pregunta, el codigo entero de ese json que te devuelve?

Comment: Lo acabo de agregar,gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para habilitar `CORS` puede usar la opción [`crossDomain`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Así por ejemplo:

```js
$('#consultar').on('click', function() {
  var cuit = $('#cuit').val();
  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://soa.afip.gob.ar/sr-padron/v2/persona/'+cuit+'?format=json',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    crossDomain: true
  })
  .done(function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
      console.log('Exito: ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
    } else {
      console.log('ERROR: ' + response.error.mensaje);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
CUIT: <input type="text" id="cuit" />
<button id="consultar">CONSULTAR</button>
```

Comment: gracias,funciona perfecto.